# MySQL keeps crashing on Centos

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, centos

```
141210 14:04:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

141210 14:04:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

141210 14:04:29 [Note] libgovernor.so not found

141210 14:04:29 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is  deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

141210 14:04:29 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a  future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.

141210 14:04:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

141210 14:04:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

141210 14:04:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins

141210 14:04:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

141210 14:04:29 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

141210 14:04:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.0G

141210 14:04:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

141210 14:04:29 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.

141210 14:04:37  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start

141210 14:04:38 InnoDB: 5.5.36 started; log sequence number 1528598520104

141210 14:04:38 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306

141210 14:04:38 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';

141210 14:04:38 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.

141210 14:04:38 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ ' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

141210 14:04:38 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events

141210 14:04:38 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.

Version: '5.5.36-cll-lve'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server  (GPL) by Atomicorp

141210 14:06:33 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
```

Any idea what that might be ? This is the issue so far, And somehow it keeps crashing.. is there anything obvious, cause i dont see any reason for it to crash. Does anyone have any idea how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the owner.

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

and make sure that "/var" and "/var/lib" retain their root.root ownership and 755 chmod.
Let me know if it solve your problem.

---

EDIT:
Please, just add the following code line option to "my.cnf" file under the [mysqld] section:

```
ignore-db-dir = lost+found
```

then restart mysql service.

Comment: Its already set that way.
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root     4096 Oct 20 11:07 var

drwxr-xr-x. 25 root root  4096 Sep 17 10:25 lib

drwxr-xr-x. 65 mysql   mysql 4096 Dec 10 14:06 mysql

Comment: This error starts to show now.

141210 15:48:23 [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'lost+found'
141210 18:00:01 [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'lost+found'
141211  9:19:30 [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'lost+found'
141211  9:22:43 [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'lost+found'
141211  9:30:40 [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'lost+found'

Comment: Please, can you tell me what's in the mysql folder?

Comment: Which mysql version are you using?

Comment: Please, also execute following query "SHOW DATABASES" and print here the results.

Comment: 1) MySQL folder there is the databases that there, and this is the other folders tho.
drwx------.  2 mysql mysql      4096 Dec 11 10:04 lost@002bfound
drwx------.  2 mysql mysql      4096 Apr 28  2013 lost+found
srwxrwxrwx.  1 mysql mysql         0 Dec 11 10:07 mysql.sock

2) Server version: 5.5.36-cll-lve MySQL
3)
+---------------------+
| Database            |
+---------------------+
| information_schema  |
| #mysql50#lost+found |
| mysql               |
| lost+found          |
+---------------------+

Comment: Ok, please read my first answer. I've just edited it adding a possible solution. Let me know if it helps.